# how do I know the locations of the pixels with respective to the camera in centimeters or millimeters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, image, image-processing, opencv

To figure the 3D location of the pixels in the image, how do I know the locations of the pixels with respective to the camera in centimeters or millimeters?

Comment: This sounds impossible to me. For example, how would you distinguish between a picture of the Washington Monument from 100 feet away, and a picture of a 5 inch tall replica of the Washington Monument from 1 foot away?

Comment: You will need a known (and clearly visible) reference sub-image inside your arbitrary image. If you know the size of this object in resultant units and the camera's optical properties, it should be possible to work out "real-distance" using the image.

Comment: @Kevin : sorry i didn't mention that this a part of camera calibration.i got the camera matrix, and extrinsic matrix.so i can measure the location of world coordinate system from a image coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Try a couple of these sites

http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/

http://autodesk.blogs.com/between_the_lines/2011/10/from-iphone-4s-photo-to-3d-model.html

https://superuser.com/questions/30053/is-there-any-free-open-source-software-that-converts-photos-to-3d-models

Start here!!!

Comment: Thanks,but this is not what i am looking for. anyway i finally got the answer for my question.

Comment: I'd be very interested for you to post your answer, and maybe even an image that better explains your question also!!!